# Ubuntu asks me to insert a password in order to install third party drivers during the installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, secure-boot

As said in the title: I'm attempting to install *Ubuntu 17* in dual boot with *Windows 10*, but everytime that I install it, during the installation, it asked me to provide a password for the secure boot, but then after the reboot it doesn't ask me for a password.

This is the fourth time that I'm reinstalling it because I have huge problems with the graphics card, the NVidia GTX 1070M. I can't decrease the brightness of my display, and when I try to switch screen (I have 2 monitors) both screens go black and I have to power off the computer holding the power button.

Leaving this aside my laptop drains the battery in less than one hour. With *Windows 10* it gives me almost 5 hours...
Anyway, after the reboot I boot in the *Ubuntu* partition, but it shows me a blue window(MOk).

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI/BIOS settings and forget about it

Comment: `"...it asked me to provide a password for the secure boot, but then after the reboot it doesn't ask me for a password."`- After entering a password for secure boot, when you reboot, doesn't it show you a screen asking you to press some key for **key management** or something like that? If so then press the key(s) and complete the process. Sorry I don't have a UEFI system right now so I can't give you full dictation. However, can't you install the third-party driver after completing installation? From **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**?

Comment: Ubuntu "17" (either 17.04 or 17.10) is [EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life). You should try installing 18.04.

Comment: Do you use Nuveau or proprietary?

Comment: I'm installing the 18.04, and yes when I reboot it show the mok page to insert some sort of key, but even if I do, I can't install the video driver.. Now I turned off the secure boot, I'm trying to install it without the secure boot right now, I hope it works! I'll let you know guys, thankyou for the replies!

Comment: Good luck! However even if you install Ubuntu with secure boot, you should be able to install the proprietary Nvidia driver by opening **Software & Updates** and going into **Additional Drivers** tab.

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli If you moved to 18.04, please [edit] your question, so it does not get closed as specific to EOL. Also please add all the details and progress information directly into your question to keep the Q&A style tidy.